# Bluetooth no detected on Ubuntu 15.4

Tags: bluetooth, 15.04

I have samsung slate, i just upgrade on ubuntu 15.4 and bluetooth is not found. It was working on 14.10...

The answer of lsusb is:

```
Bus 004 Device 004: ID 10c4:ea60 Cygnal Integrated Products, Inc. CP210x UART Bridge / myAVR mySmartUSB light
Bus 004 Device 005: ID 12d1:1570 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. 
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 2232:1036 Silicon Motion 
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 04f3:0740 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 0424:2514 Standard Microsystems Corp. USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 2232:1034 Silicon Motion 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 8087:07da Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 03eb:8411 Atmel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 05e3:0727 Genesys Logic, Inc. microSD Reader/Writer
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 056a:00ec Wacom Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 10c4:ea60 Cygnal Integrated Products, Inc. CP210x UART Bridge / myAVR mySmartUSB light
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:2514 Standard Microsystems Corp. USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0483:91d1 STMicroelectronics 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`sudo service bluetooth status`:

```
bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

Is there someone can say how to get back bluetooth?

---

I'm still not able to find bluetoot but the answer at sudo service bluetooth status is now:

> ● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
>      Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
>      Active: active (running) since mer. 2015-05-06 12:44:50 GFT; 20s ago
>    Main PID: 15370 (bluetoothd)
>      CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
>              └─15370 /usr/sbin/bluetoothd -n
>   mai 06 12:44:50 achille-700T1C bluetoothd[15370]: bluetoothd[15370]: Startin...
>   mai 06 12:44:50 achille-700T1C bluetoothd[15370]: bluetoothd[15370]: DIS can...
>   mai 06 12:44:50 achille-700T1C bluetoothd[15370]: bluetoothd[15370]: Failed ...
>   mai 06 12:44:50 achille-700T1C bluetoothd[15370]: bluetoothd[15370]: Failed ...
>   mai 06 12:44:50 achille-700T1C bluetoothd[15370]: bluetoothd[15370]: Failed ...
>   mai 06 12:44:50 achille-700T1C bluetoothd[15370]: bluetoothd[15370]: Failed ...
>   mai 06 12:44:50 achille-700T1C bluetoothd[15370]: bluetoothd[15370]: Failed ...
>   mai 06 12:44:50 achille-700T1C bluetoothd[15370]: bluetoothd[15370]: Failed ...
>   mai 06 12:44:50 achille-700T1C bluetoothd[15370]: bluetoothd[15370]: Bluetoo...
>   mai 06 12:44:50 achille-700T1C systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
>   Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.

Comment: Show us the results of `rfkill list all; dmesg | grep -i firmware`

Comment: `0: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
[    0.171748] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    4.691460] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: loaded firmware version 18.168.6.1 op_mode iwldvm`

Comment: Does `ls /lib/firmware/intel` show any files?  As the `dmesg | grep -i firmware` should have shown the bluetooth firmware being loaded

Comment: `ls /lib/firmware/intel` answer: `fw_sst_0f28.bin                     ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.80.2.3.d.bseq
fw_sst_0f28.bin-48kHz_i2s_master    ibt-hw-37.7.bseq
fw_sst_22a8.bin                     ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.2.27.d.bseq
ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.0.1.2d.d.bseq   ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.3.11.e.bseq
ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.0.2.3.d.bseq    ibt-hw-37.8.bseq
ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.80.1.2d.d.bseq  IntcSST2.bin`

Comment: and `dmesg | grep -i firmware` :  `[    0.171748] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    4.691460] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: loaded firmware version 18.168.6.1 op_mode iwldvm`  so there is no bluetooth firmeware

Comment: It still don't work, i haven't a solution...

Comment: I would install 14.04.2 as it is long term support and it has the kernel that 14.10 used, so bluetooth should function

Comment: It would be a good idea to file a bug report since it worked on 14.10 and not 15.04 as a regression occurred somewhere [bug report link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug)

Answer (score 0):

You bluetooth daemon is dead.
Restart it with `sudo service bluetooth restart`

Comment: I'm still not able to find bluetoot but the answer at sudo service bluetooth status is now:

 ` ● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since mer. 2015-05-06 12:44:50 GFT; 20s ago
 Main PID: 15370 (bluetoothd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─15370 /usr/sbin/bluetoothd -n
`

Comment: the problem percisted                                                                                                `[...] bluetoothd[3069]: Failed to init thermometer ...`
and                                                                                                                                `[...]bluetoothd[3069]: Failed to init gatt_example...`